# How to report stripe-payments usage as floating point number

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, blazor

I am adding payment and subscription to my application using stripe
I want to fee the user per the usage of my system , I tried to report usage as floating point number
but cant find a way to do that , the supported method allows you send integer usage only
any suggestion to do that?

I used UsageRecordCreateOptions.Quantity , but its integer field

Comment: Use a multiple. Like use milliseconds instead of seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took vanya suggestion(look to the comments)
changed stripe price to be 0.01$ and reported the value multiplied by 100 to convert it to cents now the loss will be parts of cent when casting to integer or long , and this is accepted for me

Answer (score 0):

The `quantity` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create?lang=dotnet#usage_record_create-quantity) is indeed an integer value, therefore you will need to specify the price for the smallest unit that you are planning to use.

For example, if your subscription price is $6 for 1 hour, but you measure usage with 1-minute precision, you might want to change the price to $0.1/minute instead.

Comment: I have internal equation in my system to calculate the usage fees , so I want to report usage fees direct to stripe , I don't want to make the calculations on stripe side because the equation might be changed from time to time without changing stripe stuff

Comment: Stripe only accepts integers for `quantity` (not float), so you have to adjust your code to take that into account. For example, you could apply multiplication (and maybe some rounding) to your formula to make sure it’s always an integer.

Could you share what you are measuring? Maybe I could suggest a more specific solution.

Comment: Thank you vanya , I am reporting money values so for example I may report 250.75 , seems the only way is rounding to nearest integer

Comment: You can also set a price per cent in Stripe, then you will be able to report the value as 25075.

Comment: Thank you vanya for your suggestion , I changed stripe price to be 0.01$ and reported the value multiplied by 100 to convert it to cents now the loss will be parts of cent when casting to integer or long , and this is accepted for me